# Stopping ACL inheritance from the command line in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, server.app, acl

With the following folder structure on a file share:

```
- Department (directory)
  + User1 (directory)
  + User2 (directory)
  + User3 (directory)
```

Whenever I add an ACE to the Department directory, it's also added to all the subdirectories. So if I want User1 to be able to see all the directories inside "Department", it also adds that ACE to all the User# directories as well. I'm trying to set it up so that all users can see the User# folders, but only have access to their personal folder.

I'm doing this from the command line because I'm trying to script it. Everything has worked until this point, but from here anything I do to the outer folders gets inherited.

Comment: Care to add the specific commands (chmod ...) you are using to set the ACL for Department?